# Poll fds with different event masks using python asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, epoll

Is it possible, in python3.8(.13)/linux, to poll different fds with different event masks using asyncio library, using a poll selector.

I need to monitor for POLLIN event on one fd and POLLPRI | POLLERR on another fd, is it possible?

That's how I'm able to listen on ONE fd:

```
import asyncio
import selectors
import select

class CustomPollSelector(selectors.PollSelector):
    _selector_cls = select.poll
    _EVENT_READ = select.POLLPRI | select.POLLERR
    _EVENT_WRITE = select.POLLOUT

selector = CustomPollSelector()
event_loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop(selector)
.
.
# listen for select.POLLPRI | select.POLLERR events on a fd_1 fd
event_loop.add_reader(fd_1, read_data_cb)
.
.
.
# TODO: how to listen ONLY on POLLIN events on another fd?
.
.
.
event_loop.run_forever()
```

I can, using a selector, register another fd with appropriate event mask:

```
selector.register(fd_2, select.POLLIN)
```

but how to incorporate this registration into the event_loop, as I understand, for each fd there's an assotiation with a handler_cb to call when specified event happens, how to create such an assotiation outside of library code? It looks like not a good idea....

It's strange, but it looks like the asyncio library doesn't provide the full functionality a linux poll/epoll does.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a second reader to the loop, something like `event_loop.add_reader(fd_2, some_other_cb)`?  You can make those event handlers do anything you want, with Python code, so there's no reason why the asyncio library should (or could) do it already.  I do not understand what you mean by "create an association outside of library code".  You have file descriptors and event handlers (python function), what else is there?  What are you worried about?

Comment: @PaulCornelius Of course I can add a second reader using a event_loop.add_reader() but in this case the cb will be called on  select.POLLPRI and/or select.POLLERR events, but I need the cb being called on another type of i/o event on a fd.